# Raspberry Pi 3 won't connect via ssh over Ethernet but works over WiFi

Tags: pi-3, ssh, ethernet, windows, putty

I'm unable to connect my to my Raspberry Pi from a Windows PI with PuTTY over an Ethernet cable, but everything works fine when I try to connect over WiFi.

Everything worked fine until I put my SD card in a new  Pi to test connectivity, then the problem described above happened. Since then I have had the same problem with my old Pi when I try with my SD Card.

Comment: Did you know that the ip addresses are usually different?